# how to change font size of all app Text components in react native?

Tags: react-native

is there a way to change font size of all application `Text` components? I want to create a button that switches sizes of font by clicking. I know I can do it by changing the styles dependencies of a single component, but is there a way to do it automatically throughout the app?

Comment: Are you asking if you can change ALL the Text components without actually changing a single line of code you have already (+ not adding any import statements)? I think the only way is to use a custom text component and replace or wrap your text components somehow as @Xhirazi mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make Your Custom component `CText` and set font style there.
And Then Globally Replace `<Text` with `<CText`. Dot forget to import on top :P

In CText write code like

```
const CText = (props) => {
   let { style, children, fontSize } = props;
    
   return (
     <Text style={[style, {fontSize: fontSize}]}>{children}</Text>
   );
};
```